# Is there any way to import from root in native es module? (nodejs 16)

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

This is our project structure:

```
- project
-     a.js
-     b.js
```

In a.js I want to import b.js file using root path in the way like this:

```
import c from '~/b.js';
```

but not using relative path like this:

```
import c from '../b.js';
```

We are using native esmodule, not Babel or Webpack or something, so is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "root path"? You either do `'./b.js'` (a relative path in the same directory) or just `'b.js'` (a name to be resolved by nodejs anywhere).

Comment: It's just a example, in my code it is much more complicated than this, like: "../../../../../test.js" rather than "abc/test.js"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pretty unusual requirement. Still, node.js does support this

- through [self-referencing a package using its name](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_self_referencing_a_package_using_its_name), so if your project has a `package.json` with the name `my-project`, then you can do

  ```
  import c from 'my-project/b.js';
  ```

  from anywhere within your project, not using relative imports
- through [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_imports), so if you declare a

  ```
  …
  "imports": {
      "#b": "./b.js"
  },
  …
  ```

  in your `package.json`  then you can do

  ```
  import c from '#b';
  ```

This also works in ES modules, see the [ESM resolution algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolution_algorithm) (specifically `PACKAGE_IMPORTS_RESOLVE`). Of course, it does not work without a `package.json`, as without a [package](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html) there is no such thing as a "root path" for your project.

Comment: Okay, the "self-referencing a package using its name" is my solution

Comment: How to add intellisense for this in VSCode?

Answer (score 2):

Subpath imports also support using directories, e.g. in order to use

```js
import {UserDao} from "#dao/UserDao.js";
```

specify in `package.json`

```json
"imports":
{
  "#dao/*": "./main/dao/*"
}
```

Note:

- `#` prefix is mandatory
- `./main/dao/*` is relative to `package.json`